# HighCharts graph generation using JSON from PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, highcharts

I am creating a page with multiple graphs that are user definable.

When a graphs details are changed it is saved via an Ajax call to the server and then the graph must be recreated.

I am trying to create the graph in PHP on the server side by generating JSON to return to the browser.

So far my problem is to render the graph once I get the json data back from the server.

The problem appears to be including the series data in the json.

Here is what the JSON returned looks like:

```
{"chart":{   "type":["column"]},
   "credits":false,
   "legend":{"enabled":false},
   "title":{"text":"Turnover by Product","align":"left","y":7,
          "style":{"fontSize":"10px"}},
   "xAxis":{"title":{"text":"Total Sales"}},
   "series":[
         {"name":"BA","data":[22375004.21]},
         {"name":"FR","data":[82542490.9]},
         {"name":"GA","data":[531139.77]},
         {"name":"MS","data":[112142]},
         {"name":"ON","data":[23464497.44]},
         {"name":"PO","data":[74623237.35]},
         {"name":"TO","data":[25845184.81]},
         {"name":"VG","data":[51496496.25]},
         {"name":"WM","data":[6849331.4]}]}
}
```

When I try:

```
var cgraphdata = $.ajax({
   url: "/graphs/data/format/json",
   global: false,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {type:graphtypeID},
   async: false,
   success: function(data) {
        }
}).responseText; // json returned in cgraphdata
var rgResult = JSON.parse(cgraphdata); // convert to javascript object
// currentGraph = id of container div for current graph
rgResult.chart.renderTo = currentGraph;  // set render target
newGraph = new Highcharts.Chart(rgResult);  // create chart
```

This results in a Highcharts Error 14. If I exclude the data I get a blank chart with the title and axes.

Does this mean that the data has to be loaded separately after creating the chart (last line above)?

EDIT:
 I have checked that the values passed for each data series is numeric - The error 14 is suggestive of text being passed as a data value.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, so you should do the graph update in the success handler. Also, as long as you serve the data as JSON with proper headers, it should already be parsed in the handler and you don't need to specify dataType.

So, something along these lines.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/graphs/data/format/json",
   type: "POST",
   data: {type:graphtypeID},
   success: function(result)
   {
       new Highcharts.Chart(result);
   }
});
```

*(You need to do the correct thing in the handler of course, I'm just not sure what that would be for your case, so I summarized it :)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that I am creating the whole graph including the series data in one javascript object which I pass to the constructor of Highcharts. My latest effort has highcharts in a continuous loop.  My real question was: do I have to add the series data after creating the chart object or can it be done as I have attempted from the server side.

Comment: ah, well, if the json you return from the server looks like what the Chart constructor eats, then I don't see why that shouldn't work. Updating example.